# How to fit 10x10 rectangle, 1x10 rectangle, and 1x1 square into given area

Tags: geometry, area, rectangles

I've been given a 2D rectangle which is `18` wide and `19` long.  I've only been given shapes of the size of a 10x10 rectangle (representing 100), a 10x1 rectangle (representing 10), and a 1x1 square (representing one).  All of these shapes are 2 dimensional.

Using a total area of `342` (18x19), I am supposed to fit 3 100 blocks, 4 10 blocks, and 2 1 blocks.   How can I go about doing this?   After drawing the first 100 block, I can't see how I can even fit the other two 100's.

[I've attached an image of my drawing so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykjhB.jpg)

I know this should be straightforward, but I can't wrap my head around it ... any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You must be expected to cut up the blocks

Comment: I tried to do that, but I was told that solution was in correct ... still scratching my head ...

Answer (score 1):

You can not even fit two $10\times10$ squares. If both squares share no rows, then you need $20$ rows, that is, a height of $20$ squares, and if both squares share no columns, you need a width of $20$ squares. If both squares share a row and a column, then they share the square of intersection, so they overlap.